# json file not showing in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, json

I am very new to Node.js. I wrote a code that displays an html page on the server. There is a hyperlink that opens a JSON file but that hyperlink does not work in the server.

```
fs.readFile('./KM23TK.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8888);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a route that loads and display the content of the JSON file in the node server.

**File structure**

```
— index.js
— index.html
— test.json
```

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

var url = req.url;

 if(url ==='/'){
    fs.readFile(‘./index.html’, function(err, html) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(html);
        res.end(); 
    });
 } else if(url ==='/test.json'){
    fs.readFile(‘./test.json’, function(err, json) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
        res.write(json);
        res.end(); 
    });
 } else {
    res.write('404 Not Found');
    res.end();
 }
}).listen(3000, function(){
 console.info("Server started at port 3000");
});
```

In the index.html now you can create a hyperlink to test.json and file will be loaded. Code not tested since I do not have access to a laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can this be done for any type of file? like if I have an image in the HTML file can I add an else if for .jpg or add an else if for CSS?

Comment: Yes it can be done. But I recommend you use a web frame like express js which allows to serve static content. For example you can create a ./public folder and put all your css and img files there. For the files inside that folder you do not have to create separate routes. Also if this answer is correct please mark it correct.